# .htaccess - Redirect HTTP but not HTTPS

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https

is it possible to do the following with .htaccess?

```
http://www.siteA.com 301 redirect to http://www.siteB.com
```

while keeping

```
https://www.siteA.com
```

accessible and not redirecting?

Comment: It's possible but it's a really bad idea, because if you do that then you can't use HSTS, and it's the only good protection against MITM.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?sitea\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://siteb.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

This will redirect all http requests from sitea to siteb.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^www\.siteA\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.siteB.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```